# Kill signal to Docker Operator Airflow

Tags: docker, airflow, docker-api

I'm facing a problem with the Docker operator Airflow. I need to make graceful exit after marking task as failed. Airflow sending Signal.SIGTERM to task, but script inside Docker container doesn't get SIGTERM, it is killed without a graceful exit.
Tried to change "stop_signal", "stop_grace_period" and "init" parameters ContainerSpec object of Docker API, and it doesn't help.
How can I forward SIGTERM or SIGINT into the Docker container script with Airflow?

PS: It works if I'm starting this script in Docker locally and killing it with the command:
'docker kill --signal=INT ....'

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1: recommended *kill the child process/process tree*, then the main process.

> For graceful exit, `kill the process tree first`, then kill the process. Below you will see the two steps, which you can modify this or wrap it as a kill operator for your custom implementation based on Airflows kill commands

---

##### Step 1a

```
def kill_process_tree(logger, pid, timeout=DEFAULT_TIME_TO_WAIT_AFTER_SIGTERM):
    """
    Kills the process's descendants. Kills using the `kill`
    shell command so that it can change users. Note: killing via PIDs
    has the potential to the wrong process if the process dies and the
    PID gets recycled in a narrow time window.
    :param logger: logger
    :type logger: logging.Logger
    :param pid: process id of the root process
    :type pid: int
    :param timeout: time (seconds) to wait on a process to terminate before
                    attempting to SIGKILL
    :type timeout: int
    """
    try:
        root_process = psutil.Process(pid)
    except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
        logger.warning("PID: {} does not exist".format(pid))
        return

    # Check child processes to reduce cases where a child process died but the PID
    # got reused
    running_descendants = \
        [x for x in root_process.children(recursive=True) if x.is_running()]

    if len(running_descendants) != 0:
        logger.info("Terminating descendant processes of {} PID: {}"
                    .format(root_process.cmdline(), root_process.pid))
        _, running_descendants = kill_processes(logger, running_descendants,
                                                sig=signal.SIGTERM, timeout=timeout)
    else:
        logger.debug("There are no descendant processes to terminate.")

    logger.info("Terminating root process PID: {}.".format(root_process.pid))
    _, running_root = kill_processes(logger, [root_process],
                                     sig=signal.SIGTERM, timeout=timeout)

    if running_root or running_descendants:
        kill_processes(logger, running_root + running_descendants, sig=signal.SIGKILL)
```

---

#### Step 1 b, now kill the process

```
def kill_processes(logger, processes, sig=signal.SIGTERM, timeout=None):
    for p in processes:
        try:
            if sig == signal.SIGTERM:
                logger.info("Terminating process {} PID: {}".format(p.cmdline(), p.pid))
                p.terminate()
            elif sig == signal.SIGKILL:
                logger.info("Killing process {} PID: {}".format(p.cmdline(), p.pid))
                p.kill()
        except psutil.NoSuchProcess as e:
            logger.warning("Process {} no longer exists".format(p.pid))
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Encountered exception while attempting to kill pid "
                         "{} with signal {}:\n{}".format(p.pid, sig, e))

    logger.info("Waiting up to {}s for processes to exit...".format(timeout))
    return psutil.wait_procs(processes, timeout)
```

---

### Option 2:

> Kill the container/worker machine

```
// From a worker machine
airflow celery stop
```